# Issue with rJava, mac 10.12.6 and Java v 9 (R version 3.4.1)

Tags: java, r, macos, rjava

I continue to have trouble installing and loading rJava. I have R 3.4.1 ('Single Candle'); Java v 9 and mac OS 10.12.6.

I followed all of the steps listed [here](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3718) which included using Terminal to edit my ~/.profile to include:

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 9)

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

And making other changes to connect R to the 'right' Java. When I run

sudo R CMD javareconf

however, I get an error message that says:

warning: ‘JNI_CreateJavaVM’ is deprecated
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
JNI_CreateJavaVM(0, 0, 0);
^
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers/jni.h:1937:1: note:
‘JNI_CreateJavaVM’ has been explicitly marked deprecated here
JNI_CreateJavaVM(JavaVM **pvm, void **penv, void *args);
^
1 warning generated.

And when I run

R CMD INSTALL rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz

Everything goes smoothly until I get an error that says:

checking whether JNI programs can be compiled… configure: error: Cannot compile a simple JNI program. See config.log for details.

Make sure you have Java Development Kit installed and correctly registered in R.
If in doubt, re-run “R CMD javareconf” as root.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’

Michal from the site linked above kindly suggested to make sure that '/usr/libexec/java_home -v 9' "points" to JDK and not JRE. I am not sure how to do this. Also when I try something like:

echo $JAVA_HOME

I get:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home

How do I know if this JDK or JRE?

Due to my error messages, I think I have a JNI problem, but I am not sure how to go about STARTING to deal with that issue. Any insight regarding what might have gone wrong using Michal's tutorial would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. My original issue was in R, trying to load library(rJava) and getting this error:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found

Answer (score 0):

You can do following to test whether your Java 9 is JDK. Do following:

```
> git clone https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook.git
> cd jnicookbook/recipes/recipeNo001
> export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 9)
> export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
> make
> make test
```

If you see

```
Hello world!
```

at the end, it means your JDK can compile JNI code. Now, if it works, it means rJava is still using incorrect Java installation (e.g. one from Apple). In that case, you need to take a look inside error log of rJava to make sure what is used there.

I hope this will help you at least a little bit.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I really appreciate it! When I ran this, I got this error: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djava.library.path=:./lib -cp target recipeNo001.HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class recipeNo001.HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: recipeNo001.HelloWorld
make: *** [test] Error 1 -- any suggestion on what this means? O.o

Comment: Make sure to call: "make" before running "make test" - I missed to put this step in instructions :(

Comment: I am having the same trouble. With @mko sugestion I checked that JDK can compile JNI code, but the question now is how to make rJava use the correct Java installation?

Comment: It's good to take a look here: https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/tools/ The issue here is that R3.4 uses new clang with OpenMP support. You might have to set correctly Clang settings as well :( In general, R3.4 + macOS + rJava might require quite some effort :(

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [link](http://www.snaq.net/software/rjava-macos.php), especially:

**Administrator account user**

Issue the following commands at the terminal:

```
export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME:-$(/usr/libexec/java_home)} 
export LIBJVM=$(find "${JAVA_HOME}" -name 'libjvm.dylib')
R CMD javareconf JAVA_LIBS="${LIBJVM}" JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LIBJVM}" JAVA_CPPFLAGS="'-I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin -I$(dirname "${LIBJVM}")'"
ln -fs "$LIBJVM" /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Libraries
```

The installation worked!